# How to do base 16 for BBP algorithm to get PI

Tags: java, math

I am using the following code to calculate Pi but I get the wrong answer because the formula some how uses base 16. Wikipedia says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) that formula has to do with hexadecimal but I don't know which part of formula process. What part of the formula do you use base 16, is it the input of the formula or just the output? For eg Do I convert k to base 16 before entering k into the formula or do I input normal base 10 number into formula and convert output of formula to base 10 from base 16. The wrong answer gives a few decimal places wrong for this code:

```
import java.io.Console;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter how many decimal places you want for Pi?");
        String line = System.console().readLine();
        double x = Double.parseDouble(line);
        double y = 0.0;

        for(double i = 0; i <= x; i++)
        {
            y = y + (1.0/Math.pow(16.0,i))*((4.0/(8.0*i + 1.0))-(2.0/(8.0*i + 4.0)) - 
            (1.0/(8.0*i + 5.0)) - (1.0/(8.0*i + 6.0)));
        }
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: What result do you get for what input? The errors you get are probably caused by floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: `Math.pow(16.0,i)` would be better done by `1 << (4*i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code implements the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula correctly. It calculates an estimation of π that increases in accurary the more iterations you use:

- Enter `1`, you get: `3.1414224664224664`
- Enter `2`, you get: `3.1415873903465816`
- Enter `3`, you get: `3.1415924575674357`
- Enter `4`, you get: `3.1415926454603365`
- Enter `5`, you get: `3.141592653228088`
- Enter `6`, you get: `3.141592653572881`
- Enter `7`, you get: `3.141592653588973`
- Enter `8`, you get: `3.1415926535897523`
- Enter `9`, you get: `3.1415926535897913`
- Enter `10`, you get: `3.141592653589793`
- Enter `11`, you get: `3.141592653589793`

And that's it. Any higher input is useless, because you can't get more precise when you use `double`.

If you want to get more precision, you should use a type with more precision than `double`, e.g. `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal pi = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(1).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(16).pow(i), 30, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal b1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(4).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(8).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i)).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1)), 30, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); 
    BigDecimal b2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(2).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(8).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i)).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(4)), 30, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); 
    BigDecimal b3 = BigDecimal.valueOf(1).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(8).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i)).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(5)), 30, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); 
    BigDecimal b4 = BigDecimal.valueOf(1).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(8).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i)).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(6)), 30, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); 
    BigDecimal b = b1.subtract(b2).subtract(b3).subtract(b4);
    pi = pi.add(a.multiply(b));
}
```

- Enter `10`, you get: `3.141592653589793129614170564040940187329961242598487417146011`
- Enter `100`, you get: `3.141592653589793238462643383279097710627677399356070777774427`

The more precision you use (here set by the parameter `30` in the `divide` method of `BigDecimal`) and the more iterations you run, the better the approximation of π will be.

Comment: Are you sure the input or output does not have to be in base 16. The wikipedia website says 'The Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula (BBP formula) is a spigot algorithm for computing the nth binary digit of the mathematical constant π using base-16 representation.'.

Comment: @MatthewReading expressions work on *values*, irrelevant of bases. This formula just has a nice property that you can calculate separately each digit in base 16. It doesn't mean that it has to be calculated on base 16. If you want to get the digits read [BBP digit-extraction algorithm for π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_%CF%80)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate the answer. The answer helped me.